# Passing React State Between Imported Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I am trying to pass state from parent to child using React, however both components are imported and therefor the state variables of the parent component are not declared.

I have two components both exported from the same file. The first component is a wrapper for the second.  This component has a useEffect function which find its height and width and set these values to hook state.

```
export const TooltipWrapper = ({ children, ariaLabel, ...props }) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
     React.useEffect(() => {
       if (ref.current && ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
         setWidth(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
       }
       if (ref.current && ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
         setHeight(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().height);
       }
     });
  return <TooltipDiv>{children}</TooltipDiv>;
```

The next component which is exported from the same file looks like this

```
export const Tooltip = ({
  ariaLabel,
  icon,
  iconDescription,
  text,
  modifiers,
  wrapperWidth,
}) => {
  return (
    <TooltipContainer
      aria-label={ariaLabel}
      width={wrapperWidth}
    >
      <TooltipArrow data-testid="tooltip-arrow" modifiers={modifiers} />
      <TooltipLabel
        aria-label={ariaLabel}
      >
        {text}
      </TooltipLabel>
    </TooltipContainer>
  );
};
```

The component `Tooltip` is expecting a prop `wrapperWidth`.  This is where I want to pass in the width hook value from the `TooltipWrapper` component.

Both components are imported into my App component

```
import React from "react";
import { GlobalStyle } from "./pattern-library/utils";
import { Tooltip, TooltipWrapper } from "./pattern-library/components/";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ padding: "2rem", position: "relative" }}>
        <TooltipWrapper>
          <button style={{ position: "relative" }}>click </button>
          <Tooltip
            modifiers={["right"]}
            text="changing width"
            wrapperWidth={width}
          />
        </TooltipWrapper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I am told that width is not defined, which I expect since I'm not declaring width in this file.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can access the `width` and `height` state value for the parent component within the App file?

Comment: [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) could work:

Add a `renderTooltip` prop to `<TooltipWrapper>`:

```
<TooltipWrapper renderTooltip={({ width }) => <Tooltip ...existing wrapperWidth={width} />}>
  <button style={{ position: 'relative' }}>click</button>
</TooltipWrapper>
```

NB. `...existing` is just the other props you are using with `Tooltip`

And then update the return of `<TooltipWrapper>`:

```
return (
  <TooltipDiv>
    {children}
    props.renderTooltip({ width }); 
  </TooltipDiv>
);
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track.  I haven't used render props with hooks before. When I try this solution I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" on the `<TooltipWrapper>`

Comment: you have other props in that on `...props`, so it would just be `props.renderTooltip()`; updated answer

Comment: I think this will work if I pull out the `...existing`.  I'm not sure what that part is doing.

Comment: that was just referencing your existing props to save me typing them all out